# Powershell select-string substring

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am currently reading the contents of a file and returning a pattern which gets one line. I am able to get the correct line by itself now. How do I do a substring function on the $RunTimeLine result to return the first four characters?

```
[string] $RunTimeLine = Select-String -Path $IDCSwiftFlowXMLFile -pattern "<time>" | ForEach-Object {$_.Line}
```

OUTPUT of $RunTimeLine  >>>>>>>   30 5 * * 2-6 2

I have attempted doing the following but it isn't returning anything

```
$StartTime = $RunTimeLine.substring(0,4)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The String.Substring method should work *IF* you have a string.  If you execute:

```
$StartTime = $RunTime.substring(0,4)
```

it doesn't return anything because the result is assigned to $StartTime.  What does this output:

```
$StartTime
```

If nothing then try `$StartTime -eq $null`.  Is it possible the first four chars are whitespace so that it appears there is no output.  You could check that with `$StartTime.Length`.

Comment: How is that different than what OP did?

Comment: but you forgot to output it, like keith edited his answer to show. when you set a variable `$startime = ...` it saves the output. to show it, you have to call it `$starttime`. an alternative would be to just output instead of saving it. `$RunTimeLine.substring(0,4)`

Comment: I outputted it and there was a bunch of white space for the missing for the file name and line number... I supposed this helped me in the right direction. Cheers Keith.