# Powershell Regex next four characters

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to come up with a regex expression to get **< Time >** followed by  the next four characters.

I'm reading a file and can find the **< Time >** part but not able to get the next four characters. What's the syntax for this in Regex?

This is my syntax I have at the moment:

```
[string] $RunTimeLine = (Select-String -Path $IDCSwiftFlowXMLFile -pattern "<time>")
$RunTime = [regex]::match($RunTimeLine,"'<Time>".Groups[0].Value
```

I have tried adding {4} directly after the time tag but this returned nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't you get a non-regex solution to this from Keith in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588279/powershell-select-string-substring ? And please provide sample of the xml file so we get to see the format of the content(ex. are there spaces before the characters). Also, specify if you consider space a character or not, because regex cares about that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your document is an XML one. Why would you use a regexp to access a node value?

```
$myDoc = [xml] (Get-Content $IDCSwiftFlowXMLFile)
$timeNodes = $myDoc.GetElementsByTagName("time")
foreach ($node in $timeNodes)
{
    $time = $node.InnerXML
}
```

Comment: The file, when read as an XML file breaks in Powershell so I'm not doing that... I just need the correct reg expression for the line.

Comment: Why (an how) does it break?

Comment: when I put in your above statement.. the error is
Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "Could not find file 'C:\Users\xgenadmin\Documents\flow.dtd'."
At C:\X-Gen\X-Gen3\X-Gen3\data\messages\X-GenCA\Monitoring\ProcessesEmail.PS1:71 char:16
+     $myDoc = [xml] <<<<  (Get-Content $IDCSwiftFlowXMLFile)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

Comment: Now, I'm confused. Is your flow.dtd file actually what I think it is? Could you add (part of) its content in your question?

Comment: The flow.dtd is just part of that XML document file in a tag.. For some reason it reads and comes out with that.. That's why i have resorted to reading it line by line which is fine. I just need the regex expression.

Comment: The dtd file is a xml schema validation mechanism, and the parser is throwing because the document doesnt conform to the schema. If you dont care about having a valid xml document I would recommend disabling schema validation before loading your document. 

If you are using the framework xml classes, the option to this is referenced here in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.dtdprocessing.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Would the regex query like this just work
`(?<=\<Time\>).{4}`

Should represent capture 4 characters as long as it is preceeded . Hopefully i explained that correctly.

I apologize for commenting on stale post. I just saw it as unanswered and wanted to help. I will watch for this in the future.